# Docker: Unable to redirect output to text file?

Tags: docker

So I have a shell script, a snippet displayed below

```
sudo docker start -ai <ContainerID> > /textfile.text

sudo docker cp <ContainerID>:/textfile.text /directorytomoveto/
```

where I wish to store the output of a process in a text file in the top directory of the container. The container executes the process and the output isn't displayed, which is a good sign. However, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Could not find the file /textfile.txt in container <ContainerID>
```

Anyone see a mistake or a way of fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: You are creating `/textfile.text` on the host running docker, not in the container.

Comment: I see. However, I tried <ContainerID>:/textfile.text as well and I don't think it worked. I'll give it another try though.

Comment: Nope, no luck. I tried earlier doing the commands manually via bin/bash inside the container and > textfile.txt seemed to work fine.

Comment: If you are trying `sudo docker start -ai $ID > $ID:/textfile.txt, then you are creating a file named textfile.txt in the directory name $ID on the local host.  If you want to create a file in the container, the command running in the container should redirect its output.

Comment: I have tried this but when I used docker inspect, the container was not taking > textfile.txt as an argument for some reason.

Comment: "Some reason" is probably that the CMD in a docker file is not subject to expansion by the shell.  When you invoke `cmd > file`, the redirect is *not* an argument to the command, but an operator to the shell.  If you want shell expansion, you can invoke it explicitly with something like `sh -c 'cmd > /p/a/t/h'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the container logs, you can simply get them by running `docker container logs <containerId>`. You can redirect the output to a log file directly on the host.

Moreover, as other have stated the `> /textfile.text` is executing on the host, and even if it did execute in the container, it would have overriden the container command that starts it, which will make the container process not start.

Comment: This worked for the most part. Thanks. However, part of the log of the container is in the file which is unwanted but I will figure out a way.

Comment: Okay, instead I did docker start  -ai  <ContainerID> > hostDirectory/textfile.txt and it worked perfectly. Thank you and to the others.